# Connection time out error while trying to update using sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

I am using **Sql server 2012 64bit** with **asp.net**.

When I fire an update query, sql server give a connection time out error for particular row.
It is working for some another rows. I cant understand the issue.

Comment: Post your query here..

Comment: Please provide the query and exact step where it is failing

Comment: It is possible that you are locking rows thus you are facing deadlock.

Comment: is there any trigger on table?

Comment: Here is an excellent article to get you started. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

set the `CommandTimeOut` property of `SqlCommand` to `0`.
With the following line :

```
SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand("Your Query","Your Connection");
com.CommandTimeout = 1;
```